# Firefox shortcut key for search "tabs from other windows" functionality?

Tags: firefox, keyboard-shortcuts

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> gives you `Tab Groups` in Firefox.

[image: Picture of Tab Groups in Firefox]

Once you enter the `Tab Groups`  screen in Firefox there is a little magnifying glass that can be clicked to search `tabs from other windows`.

[image: Picture of Tabs from other Windows Search in Firefox]

Is there a keyboard shortcut that allows you to switch search `tabs from other windows` directly? For instance starting from the main browser screen?

What is the shortcut key for being able to search all of the open tabs directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just start typing after pressing Ctrl-Shift-E and the search dialog will open up.

Comment: Ya know they really need to make that more obvious!

Comment: It wasn't very obvious. I couldn't see any indication of a shortcut, so I pressed a key and presto, there it was. The hover text should say include something like (start typing to start searching). That would make it a little more obvious.